# not able to hide result count in django admin list view

Tags: django, pagination, django-admin

I have added  the following in my admin file and the related pagination functions are below. But there is no change. Count is not disabled in any of the places and the list view is very slow as there are many items. My Backend is SQL server.

[image]

```
paginator = NoCountPaginator
show_full_result_count = False
```

from cached_property import cached_property
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.db import connection, transaction, OperationalError

```
class NoCountPaginator(Paginator):
    @cached_property
    def count(self):
        return 20

class TimeLimitedPaginator(Paginator):   
    @cached_property
    def count(self):
        # We set the timeout in a db transaction to prevent it from
        # affecting other transactions.
        with transaction.atomic(), connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 200;')
            try:
                return super().count
            except OperationalError:
                return 9999999999
```

Comment: Maybe will be a cache problem. 
Try to open in private tab.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example]

Simply override the admin template called "search_form.html" and remove or edit the part that shows the count.

```
{% if show_result_count %}
    <span class="small quiet">{% blocktrans count counter=cl.result_count %}{{ counter }} result{% plural %}{{ counter }} results{% endblocktrans %} (<a href="?{% if cl.is_popup %}_popup=1{% endif %}">{% if cl.show_full_result_count %}{% blocktrans with full_result_count=cl.full_result_count %}{{ full_result_count }} total{% endblocktrans %}{% else %}{% trans "Show all" %}{% endif %}</a>)</span>
{% endif %}
```

You can remove this entire block of code and the count will disappear. Alternatively, if you just want disable the link then just remove the anchor tags.